# __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'content_type' while dumping the response with application/json type in Django

Tags: json

Following are snippet :

```
record = {'polno':1,'custname':'abc','poltype':'TW'}
resp =json.dumps(record,content_type="application/json")
```

-->Got the error

Answer (score 0):

json.dumps doesn't have a `content_type` argument. See the function's [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.load).

Just use `json.dumps(record)`